# How to Import latest Paypal sdk in android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, paypal

I downloaded the PayPal SDK from this [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#paypal-android-sdk)

When I try to import as a module in my Android Studio project, it gives a path error and there is no jar file in this.

I also tried with an old jar file from official Paypal site, but that jar file does not contain `PayPalItem` class.

How can I import the latest PayPal SDK in my project?

Answer (score 1):

Follow [the instructions](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#add-the-sdk-to-your-project)

Add this dependency in your project `build.gradle` file in the dependency part :

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.1'
}
```

You should search a bit before asking question like that because this is essential and every tutorial on the internet will tell about that

Comment: i respect your words @agonist_ , i tried alot but it wont help me as am implemnting first time